# Javascript DOM element .click() doesn't work in addEventListener? (discord)

Tags: javascript, dom, events, click, listener

I threw together a quick and dirty script for discord to quickly 'react' to a message by calling .click on the div. I open the console using ctrl+shift+i and enter the code below.

```
let chat;

chat = document.getElementsByClassName('da-scrollerInner')[0];
chat.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => {
    
    let msg = chat.children[chat.childElementCount - 2];
    let want = false;
    // determine if I should react or not based on message contents
    
    if (want) {
        let reactions = msg.getElementsByClassName('da-reactionInner');
        let reaction = reactions[0];
        if (reaction) {
            reaction.click();
        }
    }
}
```

If I store reaction as a global variable and manually call reaction.click() it works and the reaction goes through. It also worked when I tried using setInterval to continuously check for a global variable and click it once it's defined. This works but neither solution is ideal.

```
let globalReaction;
// DOMSubtreeModified fired, globalReaction is set

let spam;
spam = setInterval(() => {
    if (globalReaction) {
        globalReaction.click();
    }
}, 50);
```

If there is something I am missing please let me know. Thanks.